# vhdl code for keypad interfacing

Tags: vhdl, keypad

```
 entity hex_kp is
    Port ( row : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           coloumn : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           sevenseg : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
           ca : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0));
end hex_kp;

architecture Behavioral of hex_kp is

begin

 ca <="0111";

 if(row = "0111") then

     if(coloumn = "0111") then sevenseg <= "00000110" ;
    elsif (coloumn = "1011") then sevenseg <= "01011011" ;
     elsif (coloumn = "1101") then sevenseg <= "01001111" ;
     elsif (coloumn = "1110") then sevenseg <= "01110001" ;
     end if;
end if;
```

This my part of my vhdl code for 4x4 keypad scanner for Basys2. It gives an error to "if(row = "0111") then" statement. I couldn't find why help please.

Comment: Reading an "OUT" port is invalid, unless you specify VHDL-2008.

Comment: And you aren't (supposed to be) allowed to make decisions on the values of other signals based on the value of an output -in -2008. It's a feature intended to support verification constructs.

Comment: And where is the value of signal `row` assigned?

Comment: Are you using the Digilent keypad as a Pmod device? There is the possibiliy of floating inputs ... you should enable pullups in the FPGA's IOBs.

Comment: I found the original Digilent example code for the 4×4 keypad. You have to drive `column` and read `row`! This prevents you from having floating inputs.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use an `if` statement in a concurrent context. However, `if` statements need to be within a sequential context - for instance a `process` statement:

```
process(row, column)
begin
    if(row = "0111") then
         if(coloumn = "0111") then
             sevenseg <= "00000110";
         elsif(coloumn = "1011") then 
             sevenseg <= "01011011";
         elsif(coloumn = "1101") then
             sevenseg <= "01001111";
         elsif(coloumn = "1110") then
             sevenseg <= "01110001";
         end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

However - note that if you synthesize the above, it will most probably end up giving you a nice set of latches (which you usually don't want), since you are not assigning `sevenseg` in all possible cases (if `row` is different from `0111`, or if `coloumn` doesn't match any of the `if` statements).

To fix it, either 1) use a clocked `process`, or 2) assign `sevenseg` to a default value if `row` and `coloumn` do not match one of the specified cases. For instance:

```
process(row, column)
begin
    sevenseg <= (others => '0');
    if(row = "0111") then
         if(coloumn = "0111") then
             sevenseg <= "00000110";
         elsif(coloumn = "1011") then 
             sevenseg <= "01011011";
         elsif(coloumn = "1101") then
             sevenseg <= "01001111";
         elsif(coloumn = "1110") then
             sevenseg <= "01110001";
         end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

I've added the `sevenseg <= (others => '0');` which will make `sevenseg` default to all `0`'s, if none of the specified cases are hit - if they are, they will override the added line, and set `sevenseg` to the appropriate value.

An even nicer way to do it is to use a `case` statement, since that probably better describes what you actually want:

```
process(row, column)
begin
    if(row = "0111") then
         case coloumn is
         when "0111" =>
             sevenseg <= "00000110";
         when "1011" =>
             sevenseg <= "01011011";
         when "1101" =>
             sevenseg <= "01001111";
         when "1110" =>
             sevenseg <= "01110001";
         when others =>
             sevenseg <= (others => '0');
         end case;
    else
        sevenseg <= (others => '0');
    end if;
end process;
```

Comment: I add process however now it gives error to that line.

Comment: An if statement is a sequential statement, which can be found in more than just processes (subprograms for instance). It just happens that Ayca Ekin is trying to use an if statement in a place where a concurrent statement is appropriate, which requires a conditional signal assignment statement *or* a process containing an if statement or a case statement.

Comment: The error relates to Brian's comment to your question. Show the error message as Brian suggests on Stack Exchange ([vhdl code interfacing keypad with fpga](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/199802/vhdl-code-interfacing-keypad-with-fpga)).

Comment: Ah - thanks for the elaboration, tweaked the answer a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a conditional signal assignment statement:

```
architecture behave of hex_kp is

begin

     ca <="0111";

--  if(row = "0111") then
--
--      if(coloumn = "0111") then sevenseg <= "00000110" ;
--     elsif (coloumn = "1011") then sevenseg <= "01011011" ;
--      elsif (coloumn = "1101") then sevenseg <= "01001111" ;
--      elsif (coloumn = "1110") then sevenseg <= "01110001" ;
--      end if;
-- end if;

    sevenseg <= "00000110" when coloumn = "0111" and row = "0111" else
                "01011011" when coloumn = "1011" and row = "0111" else
                "01001111" when coloumn = "1101" and row = "0111" else
                "01110001" when coloumn = "1110" and row = "0111" else
                "00000000" when                      row = "0111";
end architecture behave;
```

Note that like your Stack Exchange question ([vhdl code interfacing keypad with fpga](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/199802/vhdl-code-interfacing-keypad-with-fpga/199832)) There are inferred latches on `sevenseg` caused by using `row = "0111"` as a condition for assignment.

The above architecture gives the same result as my answer on your Stack Exchange question ([vhdl code interfacing keypad with fpga](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/199802/vhdl-code-interfacing-keypad-with-fpga/199832#199832)).

Your modified code analyzes, elaborates and the added testbench there simulates the above architecture:

[image: hex_kp_tb]

Getting rid of the latches would be as simple as removing the `row = "0111"` from the final choice in the conditional signal assignment above, or in the the Stack Exchange example using a case statement, providing an else for the enclosing if statement.

The entire code including the testbench and both architectures, predicated on using row as an input:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity hex_kp is
    port ( 
        row:        in  std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
        coloumn:    in  std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);  -- 'column 'is mispelled
        sevenseg:   out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);  -- why is 7 segs 8 long?
        ca :        out std_logic_vector (3 downto 0)
    );
end entity hex_kp;

architecture behavioral of hex_kp is
    -- signal row: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);  -- who drive row?
begin  -- this was missing
UNLABELLED:
    process(row, coloumn)  -- was 'column' (didn't match declaration)
    begin
        ca <="0111";
        if row = "0111" then
            case coloumn is
                when "0111" =>
                    sevenseg <= "00000110"; 
                when "1011" => 
                    sevenseg <= "01011011";  
                when "1101" =>
                    sevenseg <= "01001111";
                when "1110" =>
                 sevenseg <= "01110001";
                when others =>
                    sevenseg <= (others => '0');
            end case;
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture behavioral;

architecture behave of hex_kp is

begin

     ca <="0111";

--  if(row = "0111") then
--
--      if(coloumn = "0111") then sevenseg <= "00000110" ;
--     elsif (coloumn = "1011") then sevenseg <= "01011011" ;
--      elsif (coloumn = "1101") then sevenseg <= "01001111" ;
--      elsif (coloumn = "1110") then sevenseg <= "01110001" ;
--      end if;
-- end if;

    sevenseg <= "00000110" when coloumn = "0111" and row = "0111" else
                "01011011" when coloumn = "1011" and row = "0111" else
                "01001111" when coloumn = "1101" and row = "0111" else
                "01110001" when coloumn = "1110" and row = "0111" else
                "00000000" when                      row = "0111";
end architecture behave;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity hex_kp_tb is
end entity;

architecture foo of hex_kp_tb is
    signal row:         std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
    signal coloumn:     std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
    signal sevenseg:    std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
    signal ca:          std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
    signal count:       unsigned (7 downto 0) := (others => '0');
begin

DUT: 
    entity work.hex_kp
        port map (
            row => row,
            coloumn => coloumn,
            sevenseg => sevenseg,
            ca => ca
        );
STIMULUS:
    process
    begin
        row <= std_logic_vector (count(3 downto 0));
        coloumn <= std_logic_vector (count(7 downto 4));
        wait for 100 ns;
        count <= count + 1;
        if count = "11111111" then
            wait;
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

Comment: I would assume the 8th segment / 7th bit in `sevenseg : out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0)` is the dot :).

Comment: So, what are the displayed characters Paebbels?

Comment: Your code has a comment: `-- why is 7 segs 8 long?` which I'm refering to. Usually a 7-segment display has 7 cathode pins named `a..g` (one for each LED segment) and an 8th pin for the dot. This would explain why the OP declared the port as `7 downto 0`.

Comment: So what are the characters being displayed? Baysys2  UCF shows 7 seg outputs, dp and 4 cathodes.  The first one is '1', the second is '2', the third is a backward 'E', the fourth is an 'E', assuming a one is on and the leftmost is your decimal point which is common cathode like the segments and g is the next leftmost. The point was it isn't documented.